# Interpretation of Chi square distribution with 1/2 degrees of freedom

Tags: distributions, interpretation, chi-squared-distribution

How do I interpret the Chi square ditsribution with 1/2 degrees of freedom? I know that with for instance n degrees of freedom the interpretation is that this is the number of squared standard normal variables being summed, but for 1/2 degrees of freedom it seems not so straightforward to me.

Comment: A $\chi^2_\nu$ distribution is defined for all real numbers $\nu>0$ as a Gamma distribution $\mathcal G(\nu/2,1/2)$. Expanding from half integers to all positive reals makes for a larger class of distributions.

Comment: There are many ways to interpret any mathematical object.  For instance, when $X$ and $Y$ are independent variables with a $\chi^2(1/2)$ distribution, their sum has an Exponential distribution (a $\chi^2(1)$ distribution).  In this sense each is "half" of a $\chi^2(1)$ distribution.  But I'm sure there are many other ways to understand fractional degrees of freedom.  In what context, then, does the $\chi^2(1/2)$ distribution arise for you?

Comment: A $\chi^2_\nu$ variable is essentially a $\chi^2_{\lfloor\nu\rfloor}$ variable plus $U^{1/\nu~\text{mod}~1}$ variable.

Comment: @Xi'an Of course you're right!  Please ignore my reference to the Exponential.  (Or, if you prefer, change it to "the sum of four *iid* $\chi^2(1/2)$ variables has an Exponential distribution.")